# @Model Coming out as null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm just trying to connect up some simple data in a high charts graph but i keep getting a -

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in DotNet.Highcharts.dll but was not handled in user code

Model:

```
public class Weight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public float _Weight { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]

    public DateTime _DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Method that gets the view

```
public ActionResult Overall()
{
    object[] o = new object[db.Weights.Count()];
    int index = 0;
    foreach (Weight d in db.Weights)
    {
        o[index++] = d._Weight;
    }

    DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart").SetXAxis(new XAxis
    {
        Title = new XAxisTitle
        {
           Text = "Date Run"
        }
    }).SetYAxis(new YAxis
    {
        Title = new YAxisTitle
        {
           Text = "Distance Run"
        }
    }).SetSeries(new Series
    {
        Data = new Data(o)
    });
    return View(chart);
}
```

and the View:

```
@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js/themes/dark-unica.js"></script>

@Model
```

There is 100% data in my model as well.

I have a near enough perfect copy that works with the model being the same data types but just without a DateTime Field.

Comment: Include your inner exception message, there's hidden error behind that. Can you explain which perfectly working copy which includes additional `DateTime` field that doesn't exist here then?

Comment: Do you use the official Highcharts .net wrapper? You can find it here http://dotnet.highcharts.com/ and see some examples and code.